# Managing the reference style as: Authors, Journal Title(italic) Year(Bold), Volume(italic), Page

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage[super,square,compress,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

References of type `@article` are currently formatted as follows:

> Authors, Article Title, Journal Title(italic, abbreviated), Volume, Page, Year.

However, I need the references to be formatted exactly in the following style:

> Authors, Journal Title(italic, abbreviated) Year(Bold), Volume(italic), Page.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any special formatting requirements for entries with types other than `@article`?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly article does. The important formatting requirement is the bibliographystyle. I have got also some tables in my document. But I don't know if it has anything to do with article.